# How to implement a very long running background task in Asp WebAPI application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, iis-7.5, azure-webjobs

I'm writing a WebAPI application to perform a number of long running background processing tasks.

I'm noticing, that my test data loading task, is being killed by System.Threading.ThreadAbortException, even after I disable the pool recycling in IIS.
I know, that there is a way to run a very long running (a few hours long) background tasks within a Web application, but, I just do not know how exactly that is done - either some specific configuration settings, a coding technique, a Wen.config parameter, etc...
Can anyone share some practical way of doing this, please?

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7913034/best-practice-longrunning-task-creation

Comment: Or maybe this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19965342/launching-a-long-running-process-asynchronously/20650951#20650951

Comment: In Azure, a cloud service (worker role) is the most robust mechanism. In WAWS, you can use the WebJobs SDK for long running asynch processes. See http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/developing-apps-with-windows-azure/getting-started-with-windows-azure-webjobs

Answer (score 2):

You DON'T want to use IIS/ASP.Net to run a long running process, it was not designed for that.

Only use it for the initial call in Web.API to kick off your service by using MSMQ or inserting a row into a table that tells your separate process what to do.

Create a separate application - either a Console application, where you would use Windows Scheduler to periodically run the app and check for new work items; or a Windows Service, that periodically checks your work item store for work items. You can then use the ThreadPool, etc to asynchronously run your process.

Comment: With Azure WebJobs you now can add long running processes.  See my tutorial http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/developing-apps-with-windows-azure/getting-started-with-windows-azure-webjobs.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the best answer to my problem is to combine a self-hosted WebAPI with TopShelf windows service implementation.
This way I can write my WebAPI controller code the usual way, and those long running tasks will not get killed by IIS.

Thanks everyone for your help!

-Eugene